# Creating a constructor and adapter to read a xml

Tags: javascript, xml

```
 <Analysis id="1" name="Agricultural Resources" >
    <MapObjects>
      <MapObject Instance="mobject_2" name_area="Ukraine">
        <Contact>
          <Name>Testing</Name>
      <Tell>012312</Tell>
    </Contact>
      </MapObjects>
  </Analysis>
```

This is the XML ..I need to write a Constructor and a adapter that calls the fucntions.I need to fill the  Dropdown with Analysis and a HTML with a  and details..

```
 function getData() {
        var d = new Date();
        var tt = d.getMilliseconds();
        durl = 'data.xml?tt' + tt;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: durl,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml
        });
    }
```

I wrote this to extract the xml ..I need to go further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by fixing your XML, your `<MapObject>` is not closed:

```
<Analysis id="1" name="Agricultural Resources">
    <MapObjects>
        <MapObject Instance="mobject_2" name_area="Ukraine">
            <Contact>
                <Name>Testing</Name>
                <Tell>012312</Tell>
            </Contact>
        </MapObject>
    </MapObjects>
</Analysis>
```

then you could query the XML in your `parseXml` function to extract the values you are interested in. For example in order to extract the `Name` and `Tell` nodes you could first loop through all MapObject nodes and retrieve the corresponding values:

```
function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find('MapObject').each(function() {
        var nameArea = $(this).attr('name_area');
        var name = $(this).find('Name').text();
        var phone = $(this).find('Tell').text();
        alert('name_area: ' + nameArea  + ', name: ' + name + ', telephone: ' + phone);    
    });
}
```

Also instead of using some datatimes to bust the cache I would recommend you using the `cache: false` setting:

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.xml',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: parseXml
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply..But I dont want to parse the XML this way because every time there is a change in the XML i need to change the name in the code .Hence i need like a adapter to calls the constructor or different tears..For eg..in the XMl the Analysis has a Diff constructor ..function..the mapobject has a diff function and etc..they are all treated as objects ..